# Python IDLE: How to type correct indentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Mac: Maverick
Python: 3.4

I tried to test`timeit` module in Python's IDLE

```
import timeit

>>> timeit.timeit( "obj.method", """
    class SomeClass:
        def method(self):
            pass
    obj = SomeClass()
""")
```

When I tried to type `def method(self):` on the next line of `class SomeClass`, I hit `Tab`, it prompted a window showing the files inside my `Document` directory. So I hit `Ctrl+Tab` instead.

But I still got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 6, in <module>
    """)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/timeit.py", line 213, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer).timeit(number)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/timeit.py", line 122, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 9
    _t0 = _timer()
             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Can someone explain:

1. how to fix it, and
2. how to avoid the prompt of `My Document` appear?

Thx!!!

Comment: The response to <tab> within a multiline but is a known bug, #16198 at bugs.python.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> timeit.timeit( "obj.method", """
class SomeClass:
    def method(self):
        pass
obj = SomeClass()
""")
```

If you defined a class with an extra indentation in a regular python module like this:

```
    class Hello:
        pass
```

The interpreter would throw an IndentationError. The timeit method seems to parse the input string just like it would parse a regular python file, and throwing an indentation error for similar reasons. Note that your string starts with an extra (and unnecessary) indentation before the keyword "Class". Newlines are ok. Also mixing whitespaces with tabs may also cause indentation errors.

I dont have a mac and I can't recreate the "mydocument" issue so I can't help you there :(

Comment: Can you briefly explain why the indentation of `class SomeClass` matters?

Comment: Because if it's indented, what is it indented *under?* Where is the class, function, or other outer block which it is inside?

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick for working with timeit avoids the multiline quoted code problem: define your test object first and import it from `__main__`

```
>>> class SomeClass:
        def method(self):
                pass

>>> obj = SomeClass()

>>> timeit.timeit( "obj.method", "from __main__ import obj")
# 0.07362023352140716
```

Comment: Or you can use the `globals` keyword argument to provide `obj` to the environment where the `obj.method` code runs.